# SQL Server data type for day?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I need to find the correct data type for dayOfWeek attribute, and I don't think it's "date", as it's supposed to just state the day the event's happening, e.g. monday, wednesday, tuesday. Any way to implement this in a database? Thanks!