# Store DayOfWeek data in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, dayofweek

I want to save the `DayOfWeek` data as a column in a SQL Server table. Is this possible? ATM I'm saving an int and converting to DayOfWeek with a switch method, but I wish I could save and retrieve the data directly from the database.

UPDATE
I will try to explain. The user creates a recurring event, usually 2 times a week, for example, Monday and Friday. I want to create (on code run) all the recurring events in a given month, SO I want to store the DayOfWeek in SQL because for every event user can register if another user were present, late or so on..
Here a part of the code:

```cs
public static List<int> GetAttendance(int year, int month, DayOfWeek doW_1, DayOfWeek doW_2)
        {
            var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
            var attendances = new List<int>();

            for (int currentDay = 1; currentDay <= days; currentDay++)
            {
                var day = new DateTime(year, month, currentDay);
                if (day.DayOfWeek == doW_1 || day.DayOfWeek == doW_2)
                {
                    attendances.Add(currentDay);
                }
            }

            return attendances;
        }
```

doW1 and 2 comes from a little converter method made by me who read in db the integer stored by the user to create the recurring events.

UPDATE 2: I want to store data this way because I will use them for PREDICT future events by user inputs. Clear now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server data type for day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393184/sql-server-data-type-for-day)

Comment: What does `DayOfWeek` data mean in this context? Do you want to save the names of the days of the week? If so, save it as an `NVARCHAR`. If you want to keep the `int` numbers but display the names, you simply need to add a lookup table with the `int`s and their corresponding Display names.

Comment: Just store the date. The DateTime object will tell you what the DOW etc is for that date

Comment: Why an `nvarchar` @LewsTherin? The OP is Italian (according to their profile), and none of the days, in Italian, contain unicode characters. Personally, however, I'd used a Persisted Computed column (with an expression against the date) to store this.

Comment: Where would the data come from? A `date` column in the table, or another date value? It's very common to use a Calendar table for this job that contains dates for the next eg 20 years and extra fields for week days, names, months, years, quarters, reporting periods etc, in as many languages as you need. This way all you need to find the day of the week in eg Italian is to join with the Calendar table on the `Date` column and retrieve the appropriate column

Comment: A calendar table makes querying a lot easier too. You can search for records in a specific quarter or fortnight by joining with the Calendar table and filtering by the Quarter or Fortnight fields. Searching for all records in the same month as another record is again a simple join and filter by Year and Month

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Store your date value in a Date or DateTime columns and when querying, write queries with a where clause something like

   ```
   WHERE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DateColumn ) = 'Sunday'
   ```

But this will not be a sargable expression and on bigger data sets the query performance will be bad.

2. You can also store the week day in a Varchar(9) column and again use `DATENAME()` to extract the Week Day name from your date values at the time of Insert/update.

You can index this column and write simple queries like

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE DateColumName = 'Sunday'
```

This option is commonly used in data warehouse environment where reducing data redundancy is not the goal but best read performance is the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Keep storing it as an int, but you can get rid of your switch by just casting your saved int like so:

```
DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.Friday;

int temp = (int)day;

day = (DayOfWeek)temp;

Console.WriteLine(day); // Friday
```

Comment: This is ok as long as the data origin (.Net System.DayOfWeek enum) is perfectly known. However, having an integer day of week value is open to misinterpretation, since not all cultures agree on the day that would be considered the first day of a week

Answer (score 0):

Save it as a Date Column and use the following SQL functions to parse the WeekDay ID or WeekDay Name.

Using a date keeps your data structure understandable.

```
SELECT Datepart(weekday, Getdate()) 
SELECT Datename(weekday, Getdate())
```